# Constraint on associated type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to associate my typeclass with the type, which is an instance of the certain typeclass (`Show` for example).

Solution with the fundeps:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class (Show msg) => Handler msg h | h -> msg where
   handle :: h -> msg -> String
```

So I can implement the `Handler`, which will handle only data of associated type.

```
data IntHandler = IntHandler
instance Handler Int IntHandler where -- OK.
   handle _ x = show x    data Foo = Foo

handle IntHandler 1   -- OK.
handle IntHandler "1" -- Fail.

data Foo = Foo
data FooHandler = FooHandler
instance Handler Foo FooHandler where  -- Fails to typecheck, Foo is not an instance of Show
   handle _ _ = "failed"
```

**The question**: how to achieve the same functionality with the type families?

Let's try and declare the `Handler'` class and its implementation for `IntHandler'` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class Handler' h where
    type Msg h
    handle' :: h -> Msg h -> String

data IntHandler' = IntHandler'
instance Handler' IntHandler' where
    type Msg IntHandler' = Int
    handle' _ x = show x
```

Good, this type checks. Now let's create implementation for the `Foo` type:

```
data Foo = Foo
data FooHandler' = FooHandler'
instance Handler' FooHandler where
    type Msg FooHanler' = Foo
    handle' _ _ = "this won't fail"
```

But it also typechecks, but I want to prevent it to type check. So, how to constrain the result of the type function `Msg`?

Comment: What failed when you tried the obvious?  `class (Show (Msg h)) => Handler h  where ...`?

Comment: I've thied this for sure. But something went wrong... Probably my stupid mistake. Now that works. Thank you!

Comment: Then add your own answer!

Answer (score 3):

As @Carl is pointed out, it's pretty obvious:

```
class (Show (Msg h)) => Handler h where
```

It was my silly mistake... Just had to enable `FlexibleContexts`.